# How to extract a stream URL from a website using java?

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a website URL, when I browse it on the chrome a web page appears which has a streaming video. How can I know the stream URL of the video using java? Its format is .m3u8.By inspecting the chrome elements we can find the URL but I need to send the website URL to the server and know the stream URL.

Comment: have you tried sending the base URL with javascript to the server? then you can access it easily in the controller

Comment: I will send it but how to achieve the stream URL in java?

Comment: Probably the resource *.m3u8 is not the stream, rather a list of stream urls from which a suitable stream (based on screensize, quality, etc) may be selected.

Comment: can you share code snippet, which extracts (.m3u8) URL using Java

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending the url from browser to your controller with something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'your/url/to/yourController',
    data:{streamUrl:getItSomehow}
})
```

then in the controller:

```
@PostMapping("yourController")
public void processUrl(HttpServletRequest request){
    String sentUrl = request.getParameter("streamUrl")
    //now you have the url and do whatever you need to do with it
}
```

Comment: did you read my question? I want the logic to extract the .m3u8 URL from website URL. Even I'm doing the same what you did above.